# Limsup applied to Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, limsup-and-liminf

I've got a proof of Lebesgue Dominated Convergence theorem, but it is long and unwieldy--and I have exams coming up soon so I was trying to understand the proof on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem).

However, as usual I'm stuck on something they claim is "trivially" true, which means I'm just missing something basic.

They state, that as $f_n\to f$ pointwise. Then $\limsup_{n\to  \infty}|f-f_n|=0$. Why is this?

For example, what if $f_n(x)=\bigg\{\begin{split}1, &\quad 0\leq x\leq 1/n\\ 0,&\quad 1/n<x\leq 1\end{split}\;\;$ on the interval $[0,1]$

Then the function converges pointwise to zero, but wouldn't $\limsup_{n\to\infty}|f-f_n|=1$? I get that this would be true if we had uniform convergence, but is there some reason we can say this for pointwise that I'm missing?

Is it implicit that we're ignoring sets of measure zero? Are we using some fact as these functions are dominated by the integrable function $g$? What am I missing?

If I can figure out the justification for this point, then the rest of the proof is golden and much cleaner than what I was doing before, but since it hinges on this fact, I want to make sure it's valid, and at the moment I don't see it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is pointwise convergence: for all $x$ you have
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} |f_n(x)-f(x)|= \lim_{n \to \infty} |f_n(x)-f(x)|=0 $$ by hypothesis. It's not $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_x |f_n(x)-f(x)|=0$$ which would be indeed uniform convergence.

Comment: I agree, you have that for each $x$, but they then use it to state:

$$\int_S \limsup_{n\to\infty}|f-f_n|=\int_S 0=0$$

Which looks like they're applying it uniformly? Or is that where I'm wrong?

Comment: @kholli of course they are right about using it. $\limsup|f-f_n|$ is a function in terms of $x$ that vanishes everywhere!

Comment: Indeed: the integrand function is the zero function!

Comment: So here is what I'm still not getting:

In the above example we have for each $f_n, |f_n(\frac{1}{2n})-f(\frac{1}{2n})|=1$. So it doesn't vanish everywhere (there is always some value for which the difference is 1), but it vanishes everywhere but a set of measure zero (for which we can ignore for integration). So are they just implicitly using that we can ignore a set of measure zero, or is there something else that I'm missing?

Should it be just that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}|f_n-f|=0$ a.e.? Or is it actually everywhere and I'm missing something about $\limsup$?

Comment: @kholli think about the definition of $\limsup$: 

$\limsup_{n\to infty} g_n(x) := \lim_{n \to infty} \sup_{k \ge n} g_k(x)$.  Fix $m$ and consider

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{k \ge n} |f_k(\frac{1}{2m}) - f(\frac{1}{2m})|$

Clearly $f(\frac{1}{2m}) = 0$.  For sufficiently large $n$, if $k\ge n$ then $\frac{1}{2m} > \frac{1}{k}$ so that $f_k(\frac{1}{2m}) = 0 $ for large values of $k$.  Hence $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{k \ge n} |f_k(\frac{1}{2m}) - f(\frac{1}{2m})| = 0$.